# PyInstaller cannot find win32 API

Tags: python, pywin32, pyinstaller

I am trying to run `pyinstaller`, but I keep getting this:

```
Error: PyInstaller for Python 2.6+ on Windows needs pywin32.
Please install from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/
```

I have verified the existence of `pywin32`. I have also attempted to write the full path to `python.exe` to verify I was running the correct Python executable. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer! I just ended up installing CPython 2.7 over ActivePython. And, guess what? IT WORKED! Blame ActivePython.

EDIT: Turns out it was more. I had installed 32-bit ActivePython on top of 64-bit CPython. Whoops.

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to add to the above information with my lessons learned from my experience. First here is a [link to a safe download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/) of the latest pywin32. Some other links couldn't get through our firewalls.

```
Error: PyInstaller for Python 2.6+ on Windows needs pywin32.
Please install from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/
```

The above error occurs when pywin32 has not been installed or has been installed incorrectly. It **also** occurs when the **wrong version** of pywin32 has been installed. If you do not get a final **Finish** dialog and button during the installation, it probably did not install correctly. Also you can use pip to create a new environment and in that environment command window, type:

```
python -c "import win32api"
```

If you don't get any errors, the installation was performed correctly. The next thing to try in that same pip window and after you have installed PyInstaller is:

```
pyinstaller --version
```

Again if you get the error above, then you probably need a different version. 
Hope this helps someone out there as I spent hours trying to figure out why PyInstaller didn't work and kept getting the error above. There is no indication from the pywin32 installation that the installation failed.

Comment: Hehe...I think that's the root cause: 64-bit PyWin32 and 32-bit Python.

Answer (score 0):

Download appropriate version for your system and python verison from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/)

Then try install manually or by:

```
easy_install "path\to\file\pywin32-218.win-amd64-py3.4.exe"
```

Can you import pywin32?

Make sure doesn't pywin32 installation cast any errors sometimes its easy to overlook.

Also if this will not help: did you run Configure.py in pyinstaller?

Also sometimes instead of run(Windows is some kind of weirdo):

```
Configure.py
```

try:

```
python Configure.py
```

I hope it was helpful

Comment: I got the following: `close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr`. Also, I have `pythonwin`, `pywin32_system32`, `win32`, `win32com`, `win32comext`, and `winappdbg` folders, but no `pywin32`. I also have a `pywin32.pth` file.

Comment: Does error appear during pywin32 installation? If you use virtualenv create new one and start from beginning. If dont try create one and install needed things from zero many times it is helpful with package problems. Did you try also this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/asciidoc/eSOOYzEwS1o.

Comment: Ok. Will try those things. According to the directory listing I provided in my last comment, did it not install correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This is appeared on pywin32-win64 doesn't support on latest of pyinstaller. I've fix it by installing pywin32-win32 on my current state of windows 7 64-bit. Please ensure to modify everything version number to based on your current python version number under registry PATH "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore", example like 3.3 to 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Try install the 32-bit version rather than 64-bit. It works for me.